# Adding a div dynamically using append()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Kindly notify me I am explaining it well or not. I'm using `.append()` to repeat a div inside a page.

HTML

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#num").click(function () {
      $('#form').append("<div class='Box'>I'm new box by prepend</div>");   
    });
  });
  </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="form">
       Hai Add Another by clicking the button
    </div>
    <button id="num">Click Me</button>
  /body>
 </html>
```

This works good when I add a div repeatedly. But I like to call it externally like the below code.

```
 <html>
  <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#num").click(function () {
        $('#form').append($('#Box'));   
      });
    });
  </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  <div id="form">
  Hai Add Another by clicking the button
  </div>
  <div class='Box'>I'm new box by prepend</div>
  <button id="num">Click Me</button>
 /body>
 </html>
```

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `clone()`:

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#num").click(function () {
  $(".Box:first").clone().appendTo("#form"); 
});
});
  </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  <div id="form">
  Hai Add Another by clicking the button
  </div>
  <div class='Box'>I'm new box by prepend</div>
  <button id="num">Click Me</button>
 </body>
 </html>​
```

You have to create a new element before adding it.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g3GLd/)

Comment: Thanks man but clone() repeats all the previous divs created inside. i just want to add only one div per click. Is there any other solution for it.

Comment: if i use a inputbox the same value inside it gets repeated due to clone() is there any other way to avoid it?

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#num").click(function () {
       $(".Box").first().clone().appendTo("#form"); 
    });
 });
```

Comment: if you think the code helped you and its working, keep the answer as accepted as it might help for the future viewers also.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:-

```
 $("#parent_div").append('<div id="created_div"></div>');
```

Comment: i want to add a div externally from html page.

Comment: Check this out:- http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?28882-Load-external-page-into-lt-DIV-gt